# Handeling M-N Relationship in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-db, zend-framework2

With beta4 and latest beta5 the DB-Feature-Implementation appears to have pretty much finished. There's a couple of tutorials out there how to handle a single Database using the TableGateway Pattern, but it appears there is none for handling M-N-Relationships.

In ZF1 we had `findDependantRowset()` on the TableGateway which was kind of dirty, as this simply was a second Query to the databse which pretty much isn't always neccessary.

In ZF2 i expected there to be a way to have good Joins mapping to specified models, but i can't find anything within the code. Maybe i'm blind, maybe there really isn't anything like this.

Has anyone of you managed to handle joins and models all together in ZF2? If so, please be so kind to instruct me how to do it, hint me to specific points of the documentation or link me some blogpost to one who has done it.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Not solved, but within the #zftalk.2 chat on freenode it was hinted that you'd go for custom queries and map it to respective models yourself or use a ORM like Doctrine 2.
Still if anyone has a working solution, I'll gladly accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious solution if you need a generic solution is to use Doctrine ORM or Propel.

If you want to use Zend\Db, then within your concrete table gateway classes, you should write a specific method that retrieves the correct rows from the linked table. This way you can ensure that the SQL is optimised for the query that you need.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what you said yesterday :)

Comment: Yes - I thought I'd answer it here so that it's recorded for people who find this question :)

Comment: This makes things so much simpler and harder at the same time (^_^). I like ZF2