# how does one describe/impolements contraints and tables relations in Zend_DB 2.0 (zf2 beta5) mappers classes

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-framework2

In zend_db 1.x we used reference_map to implements constaints and relations in the data mapper classes. In zend_db 2.0 where should the reference map go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no referencing possible in ZF 2.0

You can see from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431542/handeling-m-n-relationship-in-zend-framework-2) that in ZF 2 you'll be either using a full blown ORM like Doctrine 2 or Propel for these kind of purposes or to write your own SQL Queries. The Zend DB Component is seen as a lightweight abstraction to handle simple task related stuff.